Flutter .of(context) methods performance in didChangeDependencies vs build
Is there any performance Issue with using any .of(context) methods (like MediaQuery.of(context), Theme.of(context), Provider.of(context) etc) inside build method instead of didChangeDependancies method in Stateful widgets.

Assuming that by the .of(context) calls you mean dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType (as it's used in Theme.of, MediaQuery.of, or Provider.of (with listen true).
No, both didChangeDependencies of a stateful widget and build of both stateless and stateful widgets will be called when the dependency of your widget decides to notify (the updateShouldNotify of that inherited widget returned true).
Just an FYI, that when it comes to MediaQuery.of method specifically, if you need only a concrete property of the MediaQueryData, it's better to use a corresponding method, e.g. MediaQuery.paddingOf or .platformBrightnessOf:

Since it is typical that the widget only requires a subset of properties of the MediaQueryData object, prefer using the more specific methods (for example: MediaQuery.sizeOf and MediaQuery.paddingOf), as those methods will not cause a widget to rebuild when unrelated properties are updated.
— MediaQuery.of docs

